# Property 'cordova' does not exist on type 'Window'. : ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins

In my code, I'm getting the error as `Property 'cordova' does not exist on type 'Window'.`
This is where I'm getting the error
`var browserRef = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open()`

I've also installed the `typings` but still I'm getting this error. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's just *Typescript* complaining because `cordova` is not part of the `window` object definition. There're several ways to avoid that error:

One way is to declare a `window` property of type `any`, like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

declare let window: any; // <--- Declare it like this

@Component({
  selector: 'page-demo',
  templateUrl: 'demo.html'
})
export class DemoPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, ...) { }

  public yourMethod(): void {
    var browserRef = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open(); // <--- and use it like this
  }

}
```

Another way would be to cast the `window` object to be of type `any` in the same statement where you want to use it:

```
var browserRef = (<any>window).cordova.InAppBrowser.open();
// or
var browserRef = (window as any).cordova.InAppBrowser.open();
```

If you don't want to use `any` you could also define the type of the `window` object based on the method/s you want to call:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

declare let window: {
  cordova: {
    InAppBrowser: {
      open: () => {};
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'page-demo',
  templateUrl: 'demo.html'
})
export class DemoPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, ...) { }

  public yourMethod(): void {
    var browserRef = window.cordova.InAppBrowser.open();
  }

}
```

Comment: I have used `declare var window: any;` and it solved my problem.

Comment: See my answer below for a tslint safe version for TS 4

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `any` type (which is never a good idea), try configuring this [type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types) in `tsconfig.json`. Or try to install [@types/cordova](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/cordova). Or extend the window object with the correct types. In a well-coded TypeScript project, you should never use the `any` type. At most, use `unknown` if there is no other option. Btw. in an Ionic project, you should use the Ionic native wrapper [awesome-cordova-plugins](https://github.com/danielsogl/awesome-cordova-plugins) ([read more](https://ionic.io/blog/a-new-chapter-for-ionic-native)). So you don't need to access `cordova` directly.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["cordova"]
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cordova executes only on devices, not in browser. The way to avoid errors when viewing your build in a browser is to wrap Cordova commands in a platform if statement. In example:

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

constructor( private platform: Platform, private iab: InAppBrowser ) {
    this.platform.ready().then(function () {
        if (platform.is('cordova')) {
            // your code, eg:
            this.iab.create('http://google.com/', '_blank');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: yes, I have done the same but still, I get the error. this error is showing by vs code IDE & well as in browser when I run the command `ionic serve`. I have another ionic project where I have used the same code but I don't have any issue there.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to change

```
window.cordova
```

to

```
window['cordova']
```

Answer (score 0):

In typescript 4, tslint doesn't like the `<any>` cast anymore.

It seems to now prefer this.

```js
 var browserRef = (window as any).cordova.InAppBrowser.open();
```